# How to block pointer-events when horizontal swiping?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am a JavaScript noob and I need some help to write my code. I have a scrollable div inside a (bigger) Layout that is another framework (not HTML/JavaScript). In this Layout, you can swipe horizontally BUT it doesn't detect touch events if the touch start is over the HTML div. I figured out that the reason is that HTML pointer-events take priority over the other framework's touch events. So, I decided I need to detect whether swipe is in the x-axis (horizontal swipe) and disable pointer-events for that div, OR whether the swipe is in the y-axis (meaning that the user is scrolling the div) and (re)enable pointer-events.

I don't want to ask you to write my code, but I am really a JS noob and I would be very grateful if someone could complete this code.

```js
var el = document.getElementById("swipeArea");
var swipeStartX;
var swipeStartY;

//On any touch start {
  swipeStartX = //touch.AbsoluteX ;
  swipeStartY = //touch.AbsoluteY ;
  setTimeout(checkDirection, 100);
  //set the value for the two variables, wait 100 ms and call checkDirection
//}

function checkDirection() {
  if (Math.abs(swipeStartX-Touch.AbsoluteX) > Math.abs(swipeStartY-Touch.AbsoluteY)) {
    //if horizontal swipe, disable pointer-vents
    el.style.pointerEvents = "none";
  } else {
    //if vertical swipe, enable pointer-events
    el.style.pointerEvents = "initial";
  }
}

//This is the logic I need, but I really have no idea on how to detct touch events
//And, very important: if pointer-events are disabled and the function checkDirection
//reenables them, will the user be able to scroll without having to release his touch
//and start again??

//Thank you for your help! :)
```

```css
div {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: turquoise;
}
```

```html
<div id="swipeArea"></div>
```

Comment: You need to post the framework you are using because I'm very certain there's something in the framework's API that's way better than using `pointer-events`

Comment: It's Construct 2 (Javascript for non coders) and it is a very limited tool, this is why I think it's better to write at least that part of the code. C2 has a  Touch Plugin, but you don't have anything similar to `pointer-events`. @zer00ne